# Can't import tensorflow in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm trying to import tensorflow in PyCharm, however I get an error that the module is not found.
I used pip install to install tensorflow.
Also when I look at the interpreter in PyCharm it says I have pip version 9.0.1 and the latest is 10.0.1. I have upgraded to 10.0.1 using the pip commands, and when I run pip --version it says I got 10.0.1.
I have tried both reinstalling pycharm and making new projects with no luck.

Comment: Any chance that when creating your pycharm project you selected "new virtual environment" as the project interpreter?

Comment: Try to  do pip install tensorflow from pycham terminal after that check tensorflow exist in your site-packages

Comment: @FlyingTeller yeah I am, the "existing one" is empty...?

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg If you click on the gear next to the Interpreter field, then you can search for it on your system.

Comment: @FlyingTeller worked like a charm ;) Thanks! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Files -> Settings -> Project:projectname -> Project Interpreter

It's possible, that there is a different interpreter choosen for your project then the one you installed tensorflow in.
If you're running on linux you can check with "which pip" the path to your python distro in which you installed tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

This video explain it on a very simple way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9ypGzuP6xQ

Basically, TensorFlow is not by default installed on PyCharm virtual environment. You can do it by downloading in the Project Interpreter menu

Answer (score -1):

try cleaning System Cache

> On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.

The Invalidate Caches

[Cleaning Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: Any insight on why you think this might help, especially since OP states to have used a fresh install of Pycharm?

Comment: i face have the same issues for my flask installation after cleaning the cache is worked  and also the interpreter setting if you multiple python setup install on your system