# Tensorflow in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm trying to use Tensorflow in Pycharm, I have selected the Python interpreter Anaconda in the setting, and I have added the package Tensorflow but it doesn't seem working. Plus I did the installation with the Anaconda prompt writing `pip install tensorflow` but it still not working and obtain this error:
No module named 'tensorflow'
Someone could help me? Thank you so much

Comment: then you probably dont run it with the right interpreter

Comment: How can I know what is the right so?

Comment: check this answer it may be your problem too.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170204/8474728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow can be a bit of a pain to install, the process is completely different if you are doing it outside anaconda so I won't go into that.

This documentation is particularly helpful and what I have used to get tensorflow working on my own pc
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

If you are doing cpu only stuff in tensorflow then running this in an anaconda command prompt will create an env for you to work on tf.

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

If you want to use your GPU with tensorflow then you need to check various things such as windows and linux will only support CUDA 10.0 for tensorflow 2.0. That being said you can use the following to set up a GPU env:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

Be aware that this may not result in a working env depending on your GPU ect, So I would recommend that you refer to this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

As a personal side note: I would highly recommend using jupyter lab when organising and running machine learning tasks as you can split up codes into cells with markdown decriptions of what occurs in cells which I find really helpful for readability and organisation.